Spectral measure of commuting self adjoint adjoint operators
Let $(T_1, \dotsc, T_n)$ be a commuting tuple of self-adjoint bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and let $X=\sigma_T(T_1, \dotsc, T_n)$ be its joint spectrum. By spectral representation theorem, there is a unique spectral measure $E$ on bounded Borel-measurable sets on $X$ such that one can write
$
T_k=\int_X z_k dE
$
for $k=1, \dotsc, n$, where $z_k$ is the inclusion map.
My question: Individually, one can apply the spectral theorem on each $T_k$ and obtain a unique spectral measure, say $E_k$, on the bounded Borel-measurable sets on the spectrum $\sigma(T_k)$ such that $T_k=\int_{\sigma(T_k)}zdE_k$.
Is there any way to obtain $E_k$ from the measure $E$? I guess, there is one way. To do so, we use the fact that $\pi_k: \sigma_T(T_1, \dotsc, T_n) \to \sigma(T_k)$ is a well-defined projection map onto $k$-th coordinate. Then I believe the following holds.

$\mu_k(S)=E(\pi_k^{-1}(S))$ is a well-defined spectral measure on the bounded Borel-measurable sets on the spectrum $\sigma(T_k)$;

Indeed, $\mu_k=E_k$.


To prove (1), an important step is $S \mapsto \langle \mu_k(S)x, y \rangle $ defines a regular complex Borel-measure on $\sigma(T_k)$ which I am confused about. Any help is appreciated.

What are you confused about? It all just looks like abstract nonsense.

The confusion is about how can I obtain the unique spectral measure of individual $T_k$ from the spectral measure of the tuple $(T_1, \dotsc, T_d)$.

You can just verify that $\mu_k$, thus defined, satisfies the axiom of projection-valued measure? I don’t see why you need to prove $S \mapsto \langle\mu_k(S)x, y\rangle$ is a regular complex Borel measure. (But if you want to prove it anyway, regularity just comes for free - any complex Borel measure on a Polish space is automatically regular.)

@DavidGao I am following the book by Gerard J. Murphy for spectral representation theorem. The definition of spectral measure includes checking whether $S \mapsto \langle \mu_k(S)x, y \rangle$ defines a regular Borel complex measure.

@Curious If you insist then. Regularity, again, just comes for free anyway.

@DavidGao Can you please give a reference to this fact about Polish spaces and regularity?

@Curious It’s a classical fact in descriptive set theory that other people told me about. It’s mentioned in the Wikipedia article on Polish spaces as well, but I don’t really remember a proper reference for this fact. Try Kechris’s “Classical Descriptive Set Theory”, maybe? Or try searching on this site, there probably have been questions asked about this.

@Curious It's somewhere in "Probability Measures on Metric Spaces" by Parthasarathy.
